# apache-zeppelin 0.8.0 installation while using home brew on mac OS

Tags: apache-zeppelin

i have installed java version "1.8.0_181", scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin  using home brew, and there is no error showed up while these installations.

If i ran $ spark-shell in the terminal, it shows warn but still called up scala as below:

[image]

However, while i opened http://localhost:8080/#/ and ran sc.version, it shows error as bellow:

```
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:105)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1394)
at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1215)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.compileSourcesKeepingRun(IMain.scala:432)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.compileAndSaveRun(IMain.scala:855)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.compile(IMain.scala:813)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.bind(IMain.scala:675)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.bind(IMain.scala:712)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietBind$1.apply(IMain.scala:711)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietBind$1.apply(IMain.scala:711)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietBind(IMain.scala:711)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$loopPostInit(ILoop.scala:891)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.callMethod(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:270)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.callMethod(BaseSparkScalaInterpreter.scala:262)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkScala211Interpreter.open(SparkScala211Interpreter.scala:84)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.NewSparkInterpreter.open(NewSparkInterpreter.java:102)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:62)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:617)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

how could i figure this problem?

Comment: I am getting this problem myself >:|

Comment: My problem with this error ended up being the fact that I had edited the Spark 2.3.1 package to include some libraries we needed. The `tar` command I ran on MacOS corrupted the package somehow. Even though it worked on our spark cluster nodes running linux, it gave this bizarre error when I used this same package with Zeppelin. If I use the vanilla package from the Spark downloads page, this error went away. Perhaps the brew installation of spark/zeppelin also has the same corruption I ran into when I modified the package? Just guessing.

Comment: For anyone Googling this: apache-zeppelin is not a part of brew repo at the moment. You can't install it using brew.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple issues with home brew installation, but running with docker worked for me(http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html#using-the-official-docker-image
):
"Use this command to launch Apache Zeppelin in a container.

docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.8.0
To persist logs and notebook directories, use the volume option for docker container.

docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm -v $PWD/logs:/logs -v $PWD/notebook:/notebook -e ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR='/logs' -e ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR='/notebook' --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.8.0
If you have trouble accessing localhost:8080 in the browser, Please clear browser cache."

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But after running docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.8.0, I have new error like this: docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint zeppelin (140194f5c043912c1d3eb620bbf780bdf52cbbe0922edaaf7121664d88eb18ce): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated.

Comment: It looks like some other process uses the same port. You can find what process it is by running sudo lsof -i tcp:8080 and kill that process if it is not important one or try other port.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the problem of having a Java10 installed prior to Java8. Apparently, Java version above 8.0 are not yet supported by Spark. The problem is fixable by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable to your Java8 installation.
If you don't have it:

```
brew cask install java8
```

and the default location for MacOs should be:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

If you launch your zeppelin server via the `zeppelin-deamon.sh`, then just add the export above at the beginning of the file.
You should find the zepplin-deamon.sh true file location and if you installed zeppelin via homebrew, it should be in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-zeppelin/0.8.1/libexec/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh
```